# Create a File Javascript Object in C++

Tags: javascript, c++, file-upload, html5-filesystem

Is it possible to create a File Object (Javascript/HTML5) in C++ ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)'s gsoc2012-javascript branch [here](https://github.com/swig/swig/tree/gsoc2012-javascript).